# Is there a word in English for sticking to a schedule

Tags: single-word-requests

For my customer I need to implement a measurement about how well their call center agents stick to the schedule. They need to take a break and return when they are supposed to, so the phones are evenly attended. The German word used to describe this measurement is "handhabung". How would I call this in English?

Edit:
"Handhabung" translates in google to "handling". However, I have never heard *handling* being used in this context. None of the other synonyms seemed to make sense, either. I came up with the word "strictness", but I wonder if there is a better alternative.

Comment: The English word for *Handhabung* is *handling*, as a dictionary of your choice will be quick to point out.

Comment: Yes, but "handling" does not seem to cover the description, does it?

Comment: I think the "management" sense of the German word is more appropriate in this context. Not a single word, but "**[Shift Management](http://www.clicksoftware.com/shift-management-software)**" might work.

Comment: Keeping to a set of requirements or guidelines can be called [**compliance**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/compliance). You'd need to qualify it to specify *time* constraints though - I'd suggest "schedule compliance".

Comment: Bazz, is 'Handhabung'so particular in German that it only applies to measuring how close people keep to schedules? I'm sure it is more general than that. But yes, 'Handling' would not evoke the idea well. I'd suggest not a single word anyway (English can't compete with German that way). Something on the order of 'Schedule accuracy' or 'Schedule lag'.

Comment: This appears to be closely related to the concept of *time management*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context you have described I would suggest the word you are looking for is 'Punctuality.'

> Punctuality: Exact observance of appointed times; the fact or habit of being on time. (Now the usual sense.)

This is sense 'C' in the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/154621?redirectedFrom=punctuality#eid), with the other senses largely obsolete or now rare.

Comment: Yes, I was about to put up the same answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

I think the "[management](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/handhabung.html)" sense of the German word is more appropriate in this context.  (from ‘Linguee’)

With this in mind, I checked the OED and its first entry for “[management](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/113218?redirectedFrom=management#eid)” is:

> 1. a. Organization, supervision, or direction; the application of
>      skill or care in the manipulation, use, treatment, or control (of a
>      thing or person), or in the conduct of something;

under which it notes an early connection in English between “handling” and “management”:

> 1598   J. Florio Worlde of Wordes   Management, businesse, handling,
>   negotiation.

Although not single words, perhaps  either "**[Shift Management](http://www.clicksoftware.com/shift-management-software)** [skills]," as used by ClickSoftware Technologies, a privately held company, headquartered in Israel ...

... or “**[Break Management](https://hauni.com/en/secondary/cpms/technical-modules/detail/product/shift-break-management.html)** [skills],” as used by the German company Hauni Maschinenbau AG, could describe what you want to measure, but admittedly, neither of them would describe the measurement itself, as you request.

To do that, I think you’d need to devise and furnish your customers with a relevant check-list or rubric for measuring such skills.

Comment: Thank you! Also a very good answer, but I am going to use punctuality.

Answer (score 1):

I like [timekeeping](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/timekeeping) here. Defined in the Oxford Learner's Dictionary as

> 1. a person’s ability to arrive in time for things, especially work
>        *Poor timekeeping and absenteeism will not be tolerated.*

Comment: Thank you! A very good solution. I am going with punctuality however.